# ¿Cómo bloquear la apertura de varias pestañas en mi sistema php?

Tags: php, javascript, local-storage

que tal? Tengo un sistema y necesito prohibir la apertura de mas de una pestaña en el navegador. 
**Estoy buscando que quede activa una sola pestaña en mi sistema.**

Este es el codigo que utilice-

```
<script>
    function probando(w, d, undefined) {
        var id = new Date().getTime().toString();

        if (window.localStorage.appID === undefined) {
            window.localStorage.appID = id;

            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                window.localStorage.removeItem('appID'); // Removemos la variable en localStorage
            };
        } else if (window.localStorage.appID !== id) {
            document.getElementById('prueba').style.display = 'none'; // 
            alert('asd');
        }           
    } (window, document);
</script>
```

Si alguno me puede ayudar con este tema,
Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Hi, Alan Faer! This site is purely in Spanish, consider translating your question into Spanish or migrating it to the site in English [so].

Comment: Ahi esta, gracias!

Comment: A que te refieres con prohibir la apertura de más de una pestaña del navegador? Que es lo que realmente deseas hacer? El control de las pestañas del navegador está totalmente bajo el control del mismo navegador... Cada uno tiene sus propias reglas... Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, etc. Además que es en extremo intrusivo/Obstrusivo de cara al usuario. Quizás debas formular mejor tu pregunta para explicar mejor tu pregunta.

Comment: La pestaña siempre la van a poder abrir pero lo que puedes hacer es en ese momento validar la entrada con una cookie temporal: al ingresar al sistema verifica si la cookie existe en cuyo caso no permites la entrada, en su defecto creas la cookie, y luego, antes de que cierren la ventana eliminas la cookie, espero esto te ayude, Saludos! ;))..

Comment: Exacto @fwBasic algo asi es lo que estoy buscando, que al intentar abrir otra pestaña, les salga un alert de que ya tienen una pestaña abierta. Lo intente hacer, me das una mano? Ahi pongo el codigo que utilice

Comment: En el siguiente link te dejo como hacerlo con cookies: [https://jsfiddle.net/r9vrvar8/9/](https://jsfiddle.net/r9vrvar8/9/)

Comment: @fwBasic muchas gracias, pero al implementarlo me sucede lo mismo que con el codigo que ya use. Si quiero actualizar la pagina o ingresar a otra seccion me dice que ya ingrese y no me permite navegar

Comment: @AlanFaer ¿cuál es la motivación para evitar más de una pestaña? Toma en cuenta que cualquier intento de limitación que dependa de JavaScript deja de surtir efecto si el usuario apaga el procesamiento de JavaScript en el navegador.

Comment: te he dejado una respuesta con el código planteado, este lo podras evaluar en:  [https://jsfiddle.net/r9vrvar8/10/](https://jsfiddle.net/r9vrvar8/10/) pero con una pequeña modificación que en tu caso hará que te funcione, Saludos!! ;))...

Answer (score 3):

El siguiente código te permite controlar que solo entren al sistema por una sola ventana (o pestaña), para ello utilizamos una *cookie* donde almacenamos el "**username**" de quien entro al sistema y este nombre lo asociamos a *window.name*, nombre de la ventana (o pestaña) por donde ingreso al sistema.

```
 var user = getCookie("login");

 if (user != "") { // El usuario ya entro al sistema

  if (user == window.name) { // Valida el usuario si corresponde con el nombre de la ventana;
   return; // continua el programa;

  alert(user+" ya ingreso al sistema en otra ventana");

  window.location.href="https://google.com"; // redirecciona a otra pagina

 } else {

  while (user == "") {
   var user = prompt("User Login");
  };
  document.write(user+" acaba de entrar al sistema");
  setCookie("login", user, 1);

  window.name=user;             // Asigna el Usuario como nombre de la ventana o pestaña;

  window.onbeforeunload = exitLogin;
 };

function exitLogin() {
 setCookie("login", "", -1);
};

function getCookie(cname) {
 var name = cname + "=";
 var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
 var ca = decodedCookie.split(";");
 for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
  var c = ca[i];
  while (c.charAt(0) == " ") {
   c = c.substring(1);
  };
  if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
   return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
  };
 };
 return "";
};

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
 var d = new Date();
 d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
 var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
 document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
};
```

Puedes evaluar el codigo en el siguiente link: https://jsfiddle.net/r9vrvar8/10/

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un acceso directo de tu sistema con Chrome, al hacerlo solo se podrá navegar dentro de él como si fuera otra aplicación más.

Para hacerlo abre tu aplicacion en Chrome, luego vas a **Customize and control Google Chrome** > **More tools** > **Add to desktop..**

[image: Agregar a escritorio]

Luego se desplegará un cuadro en donde se deberá agregar el nombre del acceso directo y marcarlo que se abra como ventana, así el usuario no podrá abrir nuevas pestañas una vez esté dentro de él.

[image: cuadro]